# Is there an error with Euler angles in Goldstein's Classical Mechanics?

Tags: matrices, physics, rotations

In his book Classical Mechanics, Goldstein calculates the rotation matrix in z-x'-z'' convention as follows

[image: Goldstein1]
[image: Goldstein2]

However, I believe that his procedure is false, since the rotation matrices $B$, $C$, and $D$ mean rotating in the original coordinate system about z, x and z axes, respectively (*extrinsic* rotations). Instead, we should transform these matrices to new coordinate systems using similarity transformations in order to get the proper rotations about the current transformed axes z'', x' and z, respectively (*intrinsic* rotations).

My procedure (using his notation):
$$\xi = D  x$$

The rotation matrix $C$ should be transformed to the new coordinate system: $C'=D C D^{-1}$
$$\xi'=C' D x = (D C D^{-1}) D x=DCx$$

Similarily, for $B$: $B'=(DC)B(DC)^{-1}$
$$x'=B' D C x = (DC)B(DC)^{-1}(DC)x=DCBx$$

Therefore, the actual rotation matrix should be $$A=DCB$$ and not $BCD$ as Goldstein states.

I sincerely believe that my reasoning is correct, however, I know that Goldstein's book is very distinguished, and such an important error would have certainly not be missed by mistake.

What is then the correct order for multiplying matrices to obtain the rotation matrix, and why?

Comment: None of the matrices are meant to rotate anything "in" a coordinate system. Their purpose is to transform the coordinate system itself.

Comment: @DavidK There exist passive and active interpretations of rotating matrices.

Comment: There are several interpretations of rotation matrices. All I'm saying is that you are using an interpretation that does not match what is done in the book. Changing the interpretation can change the order in which matrices need to be applied. That is why Goldstein multiplies the matrices as $BCD$ instead of $DCB$ as you expected.